# Weird Formatting for nextJs (vscode)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, next.js, format

I am using prettier as my formater.
When I read a simple JSX function it is written as

```js
function HomePage() {
  return;
  <div>
    <h1>Hello Next.js</h1>
    <p> Welcome to the home page</p>
  </div>;
}

export default HomePage;
```

however, when saved the autoformatter turns it into

```js
function HomePage() {
    return; <
    div >
        <
        h1 > Hello Next.js < /h1> <
        p > Welcome to the home page < /p> <
        /div>;
}

export default HomePage;
```

I have turned prettier off and turned most of my other extensions off yet this doesn't change, I belive it is intrinsic to vscode somehow. Anyone have a fix?

Comment: You have a semicolon after return. That completes the statement, so the rest of the function is not valid JSX. Try removing the semicolon after return.

Comment: @rb612 It is valid JSX. The function just returns nothing (`undefined`).

Comment: It is not an issue with prettier as such, you have some weird configuration that is resulting in that. Prettier itself will give this output: tinyurl.com/38khtj3e

Comment: No prettier auto added those forgot to take ";" out when pasting in just had to change the file to JSX and fixed the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the lower right, click `JavaScript`, search `JavaScript React`, and press enter (this changes the language and prettifies based on React).

Click JavaScript:
[image]

Type React then press enter.
[image]

Saving the file again should autoformat it correctly.

You can do this for all your React (Next.JS) files, or simply in the root directory of your NextJS app, open `settings.json` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> → "Open workspace settings (JSON)") and include the following:

```js
"files.associations": {
  "*.js": "javascriptreact"
}
```